# A possible closed form?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Does it have a closed form?

$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {x\cos \left( x \right) -\sin \left( x
 \right) }{{x} \left( {{\rm e}^{x}}-1 \right) }}{dx}$$

**EDIT**: no need for answer, I just found the closed form. Thanks!

Comment: maybe apply  fraction division? divide both side by $x*(e^{x}-1)$

Comment: Perhaps convert $\sin$ and $\cos$ to exponentials?  I haven't thought it out, but that might be an approach...

Comment: Please, post the closed form (my result seems to be close to -1/pi).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you have found?

$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {x\cos \left( x \right) -\sin \left( x
 \right) }{{x} \left( {{\rm e}^{x}}-1 \right) }}{dx} = \frac{\pi}{2}+\arg\left(\Gamma\left(i\right)\right)-\Re\left(\psi_0\left(i\right)\right).$$

Here $\arg$ is the [complex argument](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html), $\Re$ is the [real part of a complex number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RealPart.html), $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html), $\psi_0$ is the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html), $i$ is the [imaginary unit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/i.html) and $\pi$ is also a [famous constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pi.html).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int _{0}^{\infty}{x\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x} \over x\pars{\expo{x} - 1}}\,\dd x
=
\Re\int _{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{\ic x} - {\sin\pars{x} \over x}}\,{1 \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\Re\int _{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{\pars{\ic - 1}x} - {\sin\pars{x}\expo{-x} \over x}}\,
{\dd x \over 1 - \expo{x}}
=
\Re\int _{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{-\pars{1 - \ic}x} - {\sin\pars{x}\expo{-x} \over x}}\,
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\Re\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\int _{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{-\pars{\ell + 1 - \ic}x} - {\sin\pars{x}\expo{-\pars{\ell + 1}x}
        \over x}}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> Also
>   $$
> \totald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x}\expo{-\mu x} \over x}\,\dd x
> =
> -\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\pars{\ic - \mu}x}\,\dd x
> =-\Im\pars{1 \over \mu - \ic} = -\,{1 \over \mu^{2} + 1}
> $$
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x}\expo{-\pars{\ell + 1}x} \over x}\,\dd x
> =
> {\pi \over 2} - \int_{0}^{\ell + 1}{\dd\mu \over \mu^{2} + 1}
> ={\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{\ell + 1} = \arctan\pars{1 \over \ell + 1}
> $$

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int _{0}^{\infty}{x\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x} \over x\pars{\expo{x} - 1}}\,\dd x
=
\Re\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{1 \over \ell + 1 - \ic} - \arctan\pars{1 \over \ell + 1}}}
\end{align}